# Avoid writing of equal existing line to text document

Tags: c#

I’m new with C# need your help

In this code, I write a some word or phrase to text document with cycle loop. My question is how to avoid writing of equal line, which is already exist in text document and find it in text document, show on output?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace program_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int i = 0;

            for (;;)
            {

                Console.Write("Write phrase: ");
                var row = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine(i++ + ". " + (row));

                TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter("lines.txt", true);

                tsw.WriteLine(row);

                tsw.Close();

            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid writing duplicate lines in your file, you need a different approach. First, you need to have all of your lines in memory, then check if the user inputs a line already in memory, then write everything at the end of the program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 0;
        List<string> wordsTyped = new List<string>();

        // If the file already exists then you can load its content 
        // in memory to start your checks against the current content
        // of the file....
        if(File.Exists("lines.txt"))
            wordsTyped.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("lines.txt"));

        for (;;)
        {

            Console.Write("Write phrase: (type 'exit' to end)");
            string row = Console.ReadLine();

            // Provide a way to exit from this infinite loop
            if(row == "exit")
                break;

            Console.WriteLine(i++ + ". " + (row));

            // Use IndexOf to find if there is a match for your row 
            // and in which position in the List<string>
            int position = wordsTyped.IndexOf(row);
            if (position != -1)
                Console.WriteLine($"Already inserted. Found match at line {position+1} , type again");
            else
            {
                wordsTyped.Add(row);

                // It of uttermost importance to enclose the StreamWriter
                // in a using statement to be sure to close and dispose it
                // after the write, otherwise you could lock yourself out
                using(StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("lines.txt"))
                  sw.WriteLine(row);
            }
        }
        // File.WriteAllLines("lines.txt", wordsTyped.ToArray());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: You hsve missed `break` after last `Console.WriteLine`. And curly brackets :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I think the OP wants to continue input, but you have a point.

Comment: I mean `continue` :)

Comment: @Steve_ Hello Steve  thank for your feedback, yes this way works as it is but not for me in this case, I need this for each writing, not after exit. So If equal line already exist in file, first of all I want avoid writing of this line into a file, but I want get this line on output from document each time, because further also I want get lines which is located next or previous to this found line. I have question here about last, but still can’t figure out how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928581/avoid-writing-of-existing-line-and-find-line-through-the-index

Comment: Then you can use File.AppendText inside the loop still using the List in memory to check duplicates. Let's change the answer

Comment: @Steve well, I have no idea how to do it, maybe you can show me some working sample again just with my code  to help me understand

Comment: But let me know. The file already exists? I mean, when you start the program you would load the content of this file and check if the lines typed are already there?

Comment: I have seen now the other question. Please delete that question because there is more information in this one and the next time do not repost the same problem.

Comment: @Steve yes right it is the only thing lacks  in your new solution. if I start program again, I want check for stored data same way, if equal line already there, don't write it, just show me, as it is already done

Comment: Look at the revised answer please. Press F5, now at the start of the program there is code to load the content of the file in memory, also added a different method to check the duplicate. IndexOf returns the index of the line already in memory.

Comment: @Steve yes works, thank you for support. question deleted